# How to extract key and value pairs using regular expressions in Python for given code?

Tags: python, regex

How can I parse this code with regular expressions in Python?

```
text1 = '{% set name = "testDB" %}'
text2 = '{% set version = "0.0.1" %}'
```

I need output as in form of key and value where I can store
`key_text1 = set name` and `value_text1 = testDB`.
Similarly for `text2`, `key_text2 = set version` and `value_text2 = 0.0.1

the code I tried is follow:

```
import re

pattern = r"^{% (\w+)\s*=\s*'(.*?)' %}$"
text = '{% set name = "testDB" %}'


match = re.search(pattern, text)

if match:
    key = match.group(1)
    value = match.group(2)
    print("key:", key)
    print("value:", value)
else:
    print("No match found.")
```

and the output am getting here is No match found instead key and value

Comment: What exactly went wrong with what you have tried?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Since that looks like Jinja2 syntax, you'd have a better time just using the Jinja2 parser (only the parser/AST, not the entire template language)

Comment: these are the simple two lines from a yaml file. I didn't get the key value pair as I mentioned above.

Also I tried to load yaml file but file is not completely yaml strict as you can see '{%' '%}' this special character

Comment: How can I get key = set name and its value i.e testDB

Comment: import re

pattern = r"^{% (\w+)\s*=\s*'(.*?)' %}$"
text = '{% set name = "testDB" %}'


match = re.search(pattern, text)

if match:
    key = match.group(1)
    value = match.group(2)
    print("key:", key)
    print("value:", value)
else:
    print("No match found.")

Output: 
No match found.

I need output 
key = set name
value = testDB

Comment: Well, your pattern uses single quotes, and your text has double quotes. That's not going to work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Given the data shown, it appears that you want to isolate whatever's between two double-quotes in the string. If that's the case then:

```
import re

text1 = '{% set name = "testDB" %}'
text2 = '{% set version = "0.0.1" %}'

pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=").+?(?=")')

for text in text1, text2:
    print(pattern.findall(text))
```

**Output:**

```
['testDB']
['0.0.1']
```

Comment: This will probably break in the presence of escaped quotes.

Comment: @DarkKnight, to take into account escapement of quotes (assuming it is done with ``\``) you can use this: [`"(.+?(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*)"`](https://regex101.com/r/AZRxfs/1)